# How to scrape web data using Cheerio?

Tags: node.js, cheerio

i have solution want grab some content from url.

I have code in server.js:

```
let request = require('request');
let cheerio = require('cheerio');

let url = "domain[dot]com/title-to-video";
request(url, function(error, response, html){
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        let $ = cheerio.load(html);
         console.log($.text());
    } else {
        console("We've encountered an error: " + error);
    }
});
```

It return html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Website Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        ...
        <script>
            getplayer.setvd1('http://abc[dot]com/video34345453.mp4');
            getplayer.setvd2('http://abc[dot]com/video43243234.mp4');
        </script>
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

I want output as:

```
{
    http://abc[dot]com/video34345453.mp4,
    http://abc[dot]com/video43243234.mp4
}
```

UPDATE:
after found on internet, i am try ti fix:

```
const strvd1 = $('script:not([src])')[0].children[0].data;
const resultvd1 = strvd1.match(/setvd1\('(https:.+?)'\);/)[1];

output: http://abc[dot]com/video34345453.mp4

const strvd2 = $('script:not([src])')[0].children[0].data;
const resultvd2 = strvd2.match(/setvd2\('(https:.+?)'\);/)[1];

output: http://abc[dot]com/video43243234.mp4
```

thankyou any solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your if statement, try something like:

```
var $ = cheerio.load(html),
    script = $('script').text(),
    scriptParts = script.split(';');

console.log('{');

for (var i = 0; i < scriptParts.length; i++) {
    if (scriptParts[i].trim().length > 0) {
        var startPosition = scriptParts[i].indexOf('(') + 2,
            endPosition = scriptParts[i].indexOf(')') - 1;
        console.log(scriptParts[i].slice(startPosition, endPosition) + ',');
    }
}

console.log('}');
```

Comment: Error `TypeError: cheerio.load(...).find is not a function` find is jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

You can access script content as follows:

1)
     $('script').get()[0].attribs[//attribute name]

2)
    let $ = cheerio.load(html, {xmlMode: false});